# How to fill color in graph?

Tags: pstricks

I'm able to draw radar chart using code mentioned below, but somehow, fillcolor option is not working. Can you please suggest, how can i get it corrected?

```
\begin{center}
\psframebox*[fillcolor=white]{
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-5)(5,5)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psKiviat[rotate=0.5,yLabels={Skill3, Skill2, Skill1, Skill10, Skill9, Skill8, Skill7, Skill6, Skill5, Skill4}, labelsep=10pt]{10}{3}
\psKiviatTicklines[Dx=0.5,linecolor=black!30]{10}{3}
\psKiviatAxes[linecolor=black!30]{10}{3}
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=3pt,linecolor=black,fillcolor=lightgray]{\pskillc, \pskillb, \pskilla, \pskillj, \pskilli, \pskillh, \pskillg, \pskillf, \pskille, \pskilld}
\multido{\rA=0.5+0.5,\iA=20+20}{5}{\uput[3](0,\rA){\iA}}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{center}
```

Comment: What is `\pskill*`?

Comment: Can you please include the preamble, i.e. the packages you're using?

Comment: @PGFTricks i'm reading data from csv file, \pskill* is mapped with external CSV which is derived from DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing the fillstyle:

```
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=3pt,linecolor=black,
   fillstyle=solid,%%%%%%%%%%%%
   fillcolor=lightgray]%
  {\pskillc, \pskillb, \pskilla, \pskillj, \pskilli, \pskillh, \pskillg, \pskillf, \pskille, \pskilld}
```

and also using `opacity=0.5` you'll get a better result:

[image]